# Over ride auto-generated alt tag on image added via Rich Text field

Tags: richtext

When I add an image via a rich text (doing as port of a flexi layout approach) somehow an alt tag gets auto output, e.g:

alt="sketch2.jpg#asset:308

I wondered if there is a way to over ride or edit the HTML via the rich text field for the auto generated alt tag?

Comment: Just click the Rich Text field's HTML button and change it to whatever you want?

Comment: thats the one, thanks tried earlier I thought but must have mucked up good to go now

Comment: Cool... I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [Retcon plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) works great for DOM manipulation. You can override the attribute with a default value or remove it completely.

```
{{ entry.body|retconAttr('img', {'alt': entry.title}) }}
```

```
{{ entry.body|retconAttr('img', {'alt': false}) }}
```

Comment: Of course you've got the better answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got the `"source"` plugin defined in your `craft/config/redactor/myconfig.json` Redactor config for that Rich Text field's settings, you can click on the "HTML" button and edit the alt tag manually to whatever you wish.